# Windows form textbox values to SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I want to send the data on the text box on my windows form to the SQL Server database. I was able to connect the database but I don't know how I can send the textboxes values to their designated columns and tables. I'm having a hard time searching through net since most of the syntax aren't updated (I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017) some of the syntax doesn't work (I don't know if I'm missing something). I'll attach a screenshot of the form and also the code on the form. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eety.png)
[image]

```
Imports MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class AddBook
    Dim QR_Generator As New QRCodeEncoder


    Public Property QR_Generator1 As QRCodeEncoder
        Get
            Return QR_Generator
        End Get
        Set(value As QRCodeEncoder)
            QR_Generator = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub b_cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_cancel.Click
        Me.Close()
        MainMenu.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_quantity_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb_quantity.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
          AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_isbn_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb_isbn.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
                  AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_ddn_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb_ddn.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
          AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_year_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb_year.KeyPress
        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") _
                         AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tb_isbn_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tb_isbn.TextChanged
        Try
            qrbox.Image = QR_Generator1.Encode(tb_isbn.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Dial_save_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles dial_save.FileOk
        Try
            Dim img As New Bitmap(qrbox.Image)
            img.Save(dial_save.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub b_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_add.Click
        dial_save.FileName = tb_isbn.Text
        dial_save.ShowDialog()
        'Dim Bookname As String = tb_name.Text.Trim()
        'Dim publisher As String = tb_publisher.Text.Trim()
        'Dim isbn As String = tb_isbn.Text.Trim()
        '' at this point we have the text box data in variables

        ''Next you need a string to hold the sql database query 
        Dim sql As String = "insert into [Book Totality](isbn,book,author,publisher,dds,class,yr,edition,quantity) VALUES ('" + tb_isbn.Text + "','" + tb_name.Text + "','" + tb_author.Text + "','" + tb_publisher.Text + "','" + tb_ddn.Text + "','" + cb_type.SelectedText + "','" + tb_year.Text + "','" + cb_ver.SelectedText + "','" + tb_quantity.Text + "',)"
        Dim sc As SqlConnection
        sc = New SqlConnection()
        Dim com As SqlCommand
        com = New SqlCommand()
        sc.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MARK-HP;Initial Catalog=QR Library System DB;Integrated Security=True"
        sc.Open()
        com.Connection = sc
        com.CommandText = sql
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sc.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

[error on exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF4wU.png)

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyuFy.png)

Comment: What **specifically** doesn't work?

Comment: to be honest I don't how to send the data on text box to the database table. I don't know the syntax to do that.

Comment: Write a parameterized "Insert" query, connect to the DB, execute the query using .net classes.

Comment: If you can link a video or tutorial with the similar case that would help me a lot. I tried looking in YouTube but it seems like they are using an old format of visual studio? I really don't know. When I try their code, VS doesn't recognize them.

Comment: "When I try their code, VS doesn't recognize them" -- That is way too general for us to help you. Please provide specifics!

Comment: Your code pattern is wide open to sql injection. You desperately need to understand and start using parameterized queries. You can find examples [here](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You are mixing C# code with vb.net code. This will not work. When you find help on the internet be sure you are looking at vb.net code.

Answer (score 0):

ok lets go back to basics, we will use the first 3 boxes 
 I will assume I know the names of the textboxes

```
Private Sub b_add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b_add.Click
Dim Bookname as String = txtAuthor.Text .Trim()
Dim publisher as String = txtpublisher.Text .Trim()
Dim isbn as String = txtisbn.Text .Trim()
 '' at this point we have the text box data in variables

''Next you need a string to hold the sql database query
```

Dim sql as String = "INSERT INTO Stock (bookcolumnname,publishercolumnname,isbncolumnname) 
    VALUES ('" + tb_isbn.Text + "','" + tb_isbn.Text + "','" + tb_isbn.Text + "')

other than that

```
SqlConnection sc = New SqlConnection();
SqlCommand com = New SqlCommand();
sc.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=MARK-HP;Initial Catalog="QR Library System DB";Integrated Security=True");
sc.Open();
com.Connection = sc; 
com.CommandText = sql
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
sc.Close();
```

Comment: thank you for your reply kind stranger!
anyway i tried your code but im getting error `SqlConnection sc = New SqlConnection();` code.

Comment: This code is endangering the database! Parameters will help protect your data.

Comment: true it does need parameters but I was going for the very basic here

Comment: thanks for the replies guys! I was able to fix some of the error on codes however when i run the program and try to save, i received the error it says: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
can you guys help me with that?